# Best way to choose a random file from a directory

Tags: python, file, random

What is the best way to choose a random file from a directory in Python?

*Edit:* Here is what I am doing:

```
import os
import random
import dircache

dir = 'some/directory'
filename = random.choice(dircache.listdir(dir))
path = os.path.join(dir, filename)
```

Is this particularly bad, or is there a particularly better way?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

```
import os, random
random.choice(os.listdir("C:\\")) #change dir name to whatever
```

---

Regarding your edited question: first, I assume you know the risks of using a `dircache`, as well as the fact that it is [deprecated since 2.6, and removed in 3.0](http://docs.python.org/library/dircache.html).

Second of all, I don't see where any race condition exists here. Your `dircache` object is basically immutable (after directory listing is cached, it is never read again), so no harm in concurrent reads from it.

Other than that, I do not understand why you see any problem with this solution. It is fine.

Comment: How can i randomly select 60% files from the subfolders in variable and 40% in 2nd variable?

Comment: Hey, guess why I landed on this page?https://twitter.com/isaac32767/status/1380605988990947328

Comment: Would it be problematic if we have lets say 1 billion file in this folder ? I'm trying to load a random image from a huge dataset

Comment: Just FYI, I wanted to also avoid some files in the directory (like '.' files) so I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/2225582/559525 helpful. Basically use 'glob' instead of os.listdir().  For the question about 1billion files, would it also be a requirement to not repeat the random choice until all files have been served?

Answer (score 11):

The simplest solution is to make use of **os.listdir** & **random.choice** methods

```
random_file=random.choice(os.listdir("Folder_Destination"))
```

---

Let's take a look at it step by step :-

> 1} **os.listdir** method returns the list containing the name of
>   entries (files) in the  path specified.
>
> 2} This list is then passed as a parameter to **random.choice** method
>   which returns a random file name from the list.
>
> 3} The file name is stored in **random_file** variable.

---

***Considering a real time application***

*Here's a sample python code which will move random files from one directory to another*

```
import os, random, shutil

#Prompting user to enter number of files to select randomly along with directory
source=input("Enter the Source Directory : ")
dest=input("Enter the Destination Directory : ")
no_of_files=int(input("Enter The Number of Files To Select : "))

print("%"*25+"{ Details Of Transfer }"+"%"*25)
print("\n\nList of Files Moved to %s :-"%(dest))

#Using for loop to randomly choose multiple files
for i in range(no_of_files):
    #Variable random_file stores the name of the random file chosen
    random_file=random.choice(os.listdir(source))
    print("%d} %s"%(i+1,random_file))
    source_file="%s\%s"%(source,random_file)
    dest_file=dest
    #"shutil.move" function moves file from one directory to another
    shutil.move(source_file,dest_file)

print("\n\n"+"$"*33+"[ Files Moved Successfully ]"+"$"*33)
```

You can check out the whole  project on github
***[Random File Picker](https://github.com/THE-PHOENIX-777-TDW/Random-File-Picker.git)***

---

For addition reference about **os.listdir** & **random.choice** method you can refer to *tutorialspoint learn python*

os.listdir :- [Python listdir() method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm)

random.choice :- [Python choice() method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_choice.htm)

---

Answer (score 10):

If you want directories included, Yuval A's answer. Otherwise:

```
import os, random

random.choice([x for x in os.listdir("C:\\") if os.path.isfile(os.path.join("C:\\", x))])
```

Comment: Or if you want to emulate a wildcard : `random.choice([x for x in os.listdir("/my/path") if "pattern" in x])`.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with most of the solutions given is you load all your input into memory which can become a problem for large inputs/hierarchies. Here's a solution adapted from [The Perl Cookbook](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch08_07.htm) by Tom Christiansen and Nat Torkington. To get a random file anywhere beneath a directory:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import os, random
n=0
random.seed();
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/tmp/foo'):
  for name in files:
    n += 1
    if random.uniform(0, n) < 1:
        rfile=os.path.join(root, name)
print rfile
```

Generalizing a bit makes a handy script:

```
$ cat /tmp/randy.py
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys, random
random.seed()
n = 1
for line in sys.stdin:
  if random.uniform(0, n) < 1:
      rline=line
  n += 1
sys.stdout.write(rline)

$ /tmp/randy.py < /usr/share/dict/words 
chrysochlore

$ find /tmp/foo -type f | /tmp/randy.py
/tmp/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 5):

Language agnostic solution:

1) Get the total no. of files in specified directory.

2) Pick a random number from 0 to [total no. of files - 1].

3) Get the list of filenames as a suitably indexed collection or such.

4) Pick the nth element, where n is the random number.

Comment: Similarly language-agnostic: get the list of files in the directory, and pick one by random.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know before hand what files are there, you will need to get a list, then just pick a random index in the list.

Here's one attempt:

```
import os
import random

def getRandomFile(path):
  """
  Returns a random filename, chosen among the files of the given path.
  """
  files = os.listdir(path)
  index = random.randrange(0, len(files))
  return files[index]
```

**EDIT**: The question now mentions a fear of a "race condition", which I can only assume is the typical problem of files being added/removed while you are in the process of trying to pick a random file.

I don't believe there is a way around that, other than keeping in mind that any I/O operation is inherently "unsafe", i.e. it can fail. So, the algorithm to open a randomly chosen file in a given directory should:

- Actually `open()` the file selected, and handle a failure, since the file might no longer be there
- Probably limit itself to a set number of tries, so it doesn't die if the directory is empty or if none of the files are readable

Answer (score 1):

Independant from the language used, you can read all references to the files in a directory into a datastructure like an array (something like 'listFiles'), get the length of the array. calculate a random number in the range of '0' to 'arrayLength-1' and access the file at the certain index. This should work, not only in python.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 has the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module, which can be used to reason about files and directories in a more object oriented fashion:

```py
from random import choice
from pathlib import Path

path: Path = Path()
# The Path.iterdir method returns a generator, so we must convert it to a list
# before passing it to random.choice, which expects an iterable.
random_path = choice(list(path.iterdir()))
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what problem it solves that is not solved by the approach presented in the question.

Answer (score 1):

## This code don't repeat the file names:

```
def random_files(num, list_): 
  file_names = []
  while True: 
    ap = random.choice(list_) 
    if ap not in file_names: 
        file_names.append(ap) 
        if len(file_names) == num: 
            return file_names
```

random_200_files = random_files(200, list_of_files)

Comment: See, you're on the right track. We need to remember past choices and not pick them again until all others have been picked. Then start over. The other solutions which do not remember, as you are doing here, get to be very annoying with music and picture shuffles.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come here with the need to pick a **large** number of files from a **larger** number of files, and maybe copy or move them in another dir, the proposed approach is of course too slow.

Having enough memory, one could read all the directory content in a list, and then use the `random.choices` function to select 17 elements, for example:

```
from random import choices
from glob import glob
from shutil import copy

file_list = glob([SRC DIR] + '*' + [FILE EXTENSION])

picked_files = choices(file_list, k=17)
```

now `picked_files`is a list of 20 filenames picked at random, that can be copied/moved even in parallel, for example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from itertools import repeat
from shutil import copy

def copy_files(filename, dest):
    print(f"Working on file: {filename}")
    copy(filename, dest)

with mp.Pool(processes=(mp.cpu_count() - 1) or 1) as p:
    p.starmap(copy_files, zip(picked_files, repeat([DEST PATH])))
```