# Using Python, how do you remove files given a filespec such as "*.obj" on Windows?

Tags: python, windows

How do you remove files given a filespec such as "*.obj" on Windows?  I'm using Windows 7 and 8.1 at the moment.
Evidently os.remove does not take filespecs ("filespec" being a crude regular-expression for including wildcards such as *.txt to mean all files that end with ".txt").

Comment: First [get a list of those files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2225564/73070), then remove them.

Comment: XY problem - you want to find the list of files matching a wildcard, what you do with that list is a separate issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python glob module provides wildcard file matching. So

```
import glob
import os
for f in glob.glob("*.obj"):
    os.remove(f)
```