# Filtering only files in a particular extension - Python

Tags: python, xml

I have the following script to search for files with a particular extension, in `Python`

```
  13 def list_xml_reports(d, extensions):
  14     matches = []
  15     print extensions
  16     for root, dirname, filenames in os.walk(d):
  17         for extension in extensions:
  18             for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, extension):
  19                 matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
  20     return set(matches)
  21 
  22 print list_xml_reports("/root/my_dir", ("*junitReport.xml"))
```

However, instead of returning me only the files that end with `*junitReport.xml` that's returning me everything (`*.log`, `*build.xml`, `*.txt`, `*changelog.xml`) ... Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `("*junitReport.xml")` is the same as `"*junitReport.xml"`.  Either add a comma `("*junitReport.xml",)` or turn it into a list `["*junitReport.xml"]`.

What happened is that `extensions` received the value `"*junitReport.xml"` and when you looped over it, `extension` took the values '*', 'j', 'u', ....

The first value, '*', matched everything.

Answer (score 3):

I would use python's module `os`:
I have my files in directory: `/Users/ach/Documents/Data_Science/img/`

## Version 1:

Elegant version:

```
import os
DIR_WITH_FILES='/Users/ach/Documents/Data_Science/img'
list_png=[f for f in sorted(os.listdir(DIR_WITH_FILES)) if (str(f))[-3:] == "png"]
list_png_with_path=[DIR_WITH_FILES+'/'+str(f) for f in list_png]
```

## Version 2:

Step by Step:

**code_1**:  Import **`os`** and Give the path of the directory where your files are located

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
MY_WORKING_DIRECTORY=os.getcwd()
!ls
DIR_WITH_FILES=MY_WORKING_DIRECTORY+'/img/'
print(DIR_WITH_FILES)
```

**output_1**:

```
Users/ach/Documents/Data_Science
img                                notebooks
/Users/ach/Documents/Data_Science/img/
```

**code_2**: List the files of the directory `DIR_WITH_FILES=/Users/ach/Documents/Data_Science/img`

```
files=sorted(os.listdir(DIR_WITH_FILES))
print(files)
```

**output_2**:

```
['fig_0.png', 'fig_describe_target_0.png', 'fig_describe_target_1.png', 'test.txt']
```

**code_3**:Create two lists with the names of the files with extension `png` => `list_png`, and also another list with the name of the files with their paths => `list_png_with_path`:

```
 list_png=[]
 list_png_with_path=[]

 for f in sorted(os.listdir(DIR_WITH_FILES)):
     if (str(f))[-3:] == "png":
        list_png.append(f)
         png_with_path=DIR_WITH_FILES+str(f)
         list_png_with_path.append(png_with_path)
    
 print(list_png)
 print(list_png_with_path)
```

**output_3**:

```
['fig_0.png', 'fig_describe_target_0.png', 'fig_describe_target_1.png']

['/Users/ach/Documents/Data_Science/img/fig_0.png',  '/Users/ach/Documents/Data_Science/img/fig_describe_target_0.png', '/Users/ach/Documents/Data_Science/img/fig_describe_target_1.png']
```

You can see the file `'test.txt'` is not included in the lists.

If you want to **filter several extensions** just loop over the **`code_3`**

You can check also: [Get a filtered list of files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225564/get-a-filtered-list-of-files-in-a-directory/55439309#55439309)