# How to find filenames inside directories in Python using regexp

Tags: python, regex

I need to scan a directory for ex: `C:\Users\Jack\Work` and search for a file name which has part text part numbers ex: `Worklog_201810716_081.log`.
Could anyone please help me how can I use regexp in my code to search the file name specifically.

I have implemented the following hard code with the file name:

```
reg_lst = ["Error in log"]
for i, line in enumerate(open("C:\\Users\\Jack\Work\\Worklog_201810716_081.log")):
    if any(compiled_reg.match(line) for compiled_reg in reg_lst):
        print("Found on line %s" % (i+1))
        print("Log msg: ", line)
```

This prints the message after `Error in log` in the `Worklog_201810716_081.log` file.

I need to write a generic code where I need to also scan other log files in the directory for a text search.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. It seems that this code is doing what you want it do do, or not? Please explain.

Comment: This code specifically searches in the Worklog_201810716_081.log file for text. Along with Worklog_201810716_081.log file I have other log files (like for Ex: Worklog_201810714_078.log , Worklog_201810516_096.log and so on). I need to scan the directory for all such log files and the text inside them

Comment: Are different files on different lines in that file?

Comment: Did you try one of the things shown in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225564/get-a-filtered-list-of-files-in-a-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob.glob) or [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html?highlight=os%20scandir#os.scandir) or [`fnmatch.fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fnmatch.html?highlight=fnmatch%20fnmatch#fnmatch.fnmatch).

Try `glob(r'C:\Users\Jack\Work\*.log')` in the package `glob`. This should show a list of filename of `.log` files under the directory `C:\Users\Jack\Work`.

Untested code:

```
from glob import glob

reg_lst = ["Error in log"]

for filename in glob(r'C:\Users\Jack\Work\*.log'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
            if any(compiled_reg.match(line) for compiled_reg in reg_lst):
              print("Found on line %s" % (i+1))
              print("Log msg: ", line)
```

[Another disscusion about filtering file by name.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225564/get-a-filtered-list-of-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: btw, the filename filtering does not use `regex`. it is called `Unix shell-style wildcard` or `fnmatch` as mentioned on https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write the following code and it works successfully.

```
reg_lst = ["Error in log"]
work_path = "C:\Users\Jack\Work\"

for file in os.listdir(work_path):
  if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.log'):
    for i, line in enumerate(open(os.path.join(work_path,file))):
        if any(compiled_reg.match(line) for compiled_reg in reg_lst):
            print("Found on line %s" % (i+1))
            print("Log msg: ", line)
```

It searches all the log files in the `work_path` directory and searches the text `"Error in log"` and prints the line number and the entire text message on that line.