# How to import a file from a folder where the ending characters can change - python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, wildcard

I currently have a folder that contains multiple files with similar names that I am trying to read from. 
For example:
Folder contains files:

```
apple_2019_08_26_23434.xls
apple_2019_08_25_55345.xls
apple_2019_08_24_99345.xls
```

the name format of the file is very simple:

```
 apple_<date>_<5 random numbers>.xls
```

How can I read the excel file into a pandas df if I do not care about the random 5 digits at the end?

e.g.

```
df = pd.read_excel('e:\Document\apple_2019_08_26_<***wildcard***>.xls')
```

Thank you!

Comment: First list the files that match your specifications and then open the path of every item in that list? Like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225564/get-a-filtered-list-of-files-in-a-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use unix style pathname expansions via [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

```
import glob

# get .txt files in current directory
txt_files = glob.glob('./*.txt')

# get .xls files in some_dir
xls_files = glob.glob('some_dir/*.xls')

# do stuff with files
# ...
```

Here, `*` basically means "anything".

Example with pandas:

```
import glob

for xls_file in glob.glob('e:/Document/apple_2019_08_26_*.xls'):
    df = pd.read_excel(xls_file)

    # do stuff with df
    # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your directory with `os.chdir` then import all files which `startwith` the correct name:

```
import os
os.chdir(r'e:\Document')
dfs = [pd.read_excel(file) for file in os.listdir() if file.startswith('apple_2019_08')]
```

Now you can access each dataframe by index:

```
print(dfs[0])

print(dfs[1])
```

Or combine them to one large dataframe if they have the same format

```
df_all = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the 5-digit part to be changeable in the code, you could try something like this:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pandas as pd

mypath = '/Users/username/aPath'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

fiveDigitNumber = onlyfiles[0][17:22]
filename = onlyfiles[0][:17]+fiveDigitNumber+onlyfiles[0][22:]

df = pd.read_excel(filename)
```