# How to use bash command results as python args?

Tags: python, bash, command-line-arguments

I am trying to find all .js files in directories and gives it as arguments to python. I could collect all the files with .js using bash command `find . -name "*.js"`, but I don't know how to give these information to python. I don't want to send file name one by one. I want to send as a list the python code that handling arguments is following.

```
import argparse

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser("sh test")

argparser.add_argument("js_file", type=str, nargs ="+", help="js file names")

args = argparser.parse_args()
for file in args.js_file:
    # do something
```

Comment: You can find all files matching `*.js` in Python too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225564/get-a-filtered-list-of-files-in-a-directory

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find

Comment: If there are no spaces in the filenames, this is just `python my_script.py *.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) from a python script to do this:

```
import subprocess
cmd  = 'find . -name "*.js"'

p = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True)
files = p.stdout.decode().split()
print(files)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU find you can use `-exec +` to call a command with all the matching file names in one go.

```
find . -name '*.js' -exec script.py {} +
```

If not you can get the same behavior with `find | xargs`.

```
find . -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that foo.py is your python script, you can use this:

```
python  foo.py `find . -name "*.js" | tr '\n' ' '`
```