# How to get list files matching name in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get a list of files in a directory which match a certain name e.g in Bash the Code would be :

> BASH

```
 FOLDER="MainProject"
 FILES=`find "$FOLDER" -name "Localizations*swift"`
```

> Python

```
import os

def read_files():
    path = 'MainProject/'
    folders = []
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for folder in d:
            folders.append(os.path.join(r, folder))
    for f in folders:
        print(f)
```

Please note I am new to python hence I am struggling with this.

Comment: maybe using python;s [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) function

Comment: nice, i see You found os.walk

Comment: This question has been already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225564/get-a-filtered-list-of-files-in-a-directory#2225582

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need files in a single directory (no depth):

```py
from glob import glob
import os

def read_files():
    path = 'MainProject/'
    print(list(glob(os.path.join(path, "Localizations*swift"))))
```

If you only need file names (and not directory names) recursively:

```py
from fnmatch import fnmatch
import os

def read_files():
    path = 'MainProject/'
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        if fnmatch(f, "Localizations*swift"):
            print(os.path.join(r, f))
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with Python 3.8.10, as `f` (as returned by `os.walk`) is a list of strings, whereas `fnmatch` expects a single string as its first argument.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to look at the current dir:

```py
path = 'MainProject/'
f_name = 'Localizations*swift'
all_files = os.listdir(path)
matching_files = [file for file in all_files if file==f_name]
```

if You want to 'walk' through the current and all subdirs, make use of the os.walk function.
Also You can use some regex, to match file names

```py
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
   for name in files:
       # if name.find(f_name)>-1: # name contains f_name
       if name==f_name:
           print(os.path.join(root, name))
```