# Trying to rename multiple files using OS module (Python), getting error message :"ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to rename multiple files by importing the OS Module (Mac OS). To do this I have first split the files' titles from their extension and then the files (pdfs in this case) had an additional format specification (a4). Here's an example : "darwinism_a4.pdf". I am trying to remove the "*a4" part. So, I have tried  split the name at the underscore using this line : f_title, f_format = f_name.split("*"). At this point I have received this error message :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/me/Documents/Programming/Cody_schafer/training.py", line 10, in 
f_title, f_format = f_name.split("_")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

I have finished the code anyways to show what I want to achieve and will include it here.

```
import os


for f in os.listdir():

    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)

    print(f_name.split("_"))

    f_title, f_format = f_name.split("_")

    print(f_title, f_format)

    new_name = '{}-{}'.format(f_title, f_ext)

    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

I am thinking maybe it has something to do with all the files not having the same format? There's a file titled '.DS_Store' (for desktop services). It's put there by default.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to split a name that doesn't include the `"_"` character, so split is only returning one value. Are there any other files in that directory?

Comment: @Craig is there a way I can restrict the renaming only to certain files of a specific format? Also please see the edited version (last paragraph after code sample), can this be the problem?

Comment: @MahmoudHosny you can. But you should do your research on your own. It's been asked before.

Comment: One of many options: [Get a filtered list of files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225564/get-a-filtered-list-of-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some of the files or directories returned by `os.listdir()` do not contain an underscore. Your code needs to account for this possibility. For instance, you could do this:

```
import os

for f in os.listdir():
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    print(f_name.split("_"))
    if "_" in f_name:
        f_title, f_format = f_name.split("_", maxsplit=1)
        print(f_title, f_format)
        new_name = '{}.{}'.format(f_title, f_ext)
        os.rename(f, new_name)
```

Note also that I added `maxsplit=1` to the `split` method, as it is also possible that files may have more than one underscore in their name.

Also, you could check which filename does not have the underscore by adding a `print(f)` line under the `os.listdir()` line. It might be a directory name, as `os.listdir()` lists both files and directories.

Finally, I changed your format string `{}-{}` to `{}.{}`, as file extensions follow a period, not a hyphen. (However, this matters more on Windows than on MacOS, as Windows checks the filename, but MacOS checks inside the file to find the file type.)