# I wanted to select some specific files in my directories

Tags: python

```py
for folder, sub_folders, files in os.walk('D:\\excel'):
    print(f"Currently looking at {folder}")
    print('\n')
    print('The subfolder are: ')
    for sub_fold in sub_folders:
        print(f"Subfolder: {sub_fold}")
    print('\n')
    print("the files are: ")
    for f in files:
        print(f"File: {f}")
```

I am currently using the os.path to locate all of my files in that current directory, but I only wanted to select files that ended in "RPM_AvgCylP_PStats", I am brand new so I am not really good with the logic.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/08vwd.png

Comment: Please review the posting guidelines and refrain from using pictures of text in your question.

Comment: [str.endswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a filtered list of files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225564/get-a-filtered-list-of-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

if you can, try to use pathlib instead, since this is designed for dealing with tasks like this.

if can't, simply change the last for loop to:

```
for f in files:
    if f.replace(".txt",'').endswith( "RPM_AvgCylP_PStats"):
        print(f"File: {f}")
```

Comment: Why `replace`? Why not just `if f.endswith("RPM_AvgCylP_PStats.txt")`?

Comment: that's almost same. the only difference is that, if there are files without any extension but ends with that string pattern...

Comment: another way is -->  f.split('.')[0].endswith( "RPM_AvgCylP_PStats"):

Comment: A better option than both is to use `pathlib` and just check for `Path().name`