# how to read a file name with variable in python?

Tags: python, wildcard

I have a folder with many .csv files in it with the following format:

```
FGS07_NAV_26246_20210422_86oylt.xls
```

`FGS07_NAV_26246_` is always the same, `20210422` is the date and the most important parameter to go and pick the file, `_86oylt` also changes but not important at all.

I need to read one csv file with the same date as the operation date.
let’s think that `y` is our date part, so I tried this code, but it doesn’t give me the write name:

```
file2 = r'C:/Users/name/Finance/LOF_PnL/FGS07_NAV_26246_' + y + '*.xls'
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2)
```

How should I fix?

Comment: What's does `file2` end up as after concatenation? (by the way you're missing the closing apostrophe)

Comment: To find files using wildcards you should look at using glob - https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a filtered list of files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225564/get-a-filtered-list-of-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 1):

if you want just the specific file, you could try this one:

```
xls_file = [file for file in os.listdir(r"C:/Users/name/Finance/LOF_PnL") if file.endswith("xls") and y in file][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `glob` module:

```
import glob
file2 = glob.glob(file2)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os

all_files = os.listdir(r'C:/Users/name/Finance/LOF_PnL')
filtered_files = list(filter(lambda x : 'FGS07_NAV_26246_' + y in x, all_files))
```

and now `filtered_files` is a list with the names of all files having `'FGS07_NAV_26246_' + y` in their file names. You can add the full path to these names if you want the absolute path. You can also use regex for a more fancy pattern lookup than `in`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use join() or os.path.join() which are more standard.

```
"".join([str1, str2])
os.path.join(path_to_file, filename)
```

I hope this could be helpful. Maybe check the type of the file again also.