# Python 2.6: how to exclude filenames that contain a certain substring?

Tags: glob, python-2.6

I have 3 file in `/some/dir`:

```
$ ls /some/dir
fiot_csv2apex_nomuratest.xml  fiot_csv2apex_nomurauat.xml  fiot_csv2apex_nomura.xml
```

I want my script to extract only the file that does NOT contain substrings `"uat"` or `"test"` in its filename.

To start off simply, I'm only trying to exclude the `"uat"` substring but my attempts fail.

Here is the entire script that does NOT try to exclude any of those 3 files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET, sys, os, re, fnmatch

param = sys.argv[1]
client = param.split('_')[0]
market = param.split('_')[1]
suffix = param.split('_')[2]

toapex_pattern = market + '*2apex*' + client + '*' + '.xml'

files_dir = '/some/dir'
config_files = os.listdir(files_dir)

for f in config_files:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, toapex_pattern):
            print(f)
```

The above script will output all the 3 files in `/some/dir` as expected. The script is being run like this:

```
python /test/scripts/regex.py nomura_fiot_b
```

I attempted to exclude `"uat"` by modifying `toapex_pattern` variable like this:

```
toapex_pattern = market + '*2apex*' + client + '(?!uat)' + '*' + '.xml':
```

However, after that the script did not produce any output.

I also tried this:

```
toapex_pattern = re.compile(market + '*2apex*' + client + '(?!uat)' + '*' + '.xml')
```

But this resulted in a type error:

```
TypeError: object of type '_sre.SRE_Pattern' has no len()
```

And if I try this:

```
toapex_pattern = market + '*2apex*' + client + '[^uat]' + '*' + '.xml'
```

the output is:

```
fiot_csv2apex_nomuratest.xml
fiot_csv2apex_nomurauat.xml
```

The desired output is:

```
fiot_csv2apex_nomura.xml
```

How should I modify the `toapex_pattern` variable to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a filtered list of files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225564/get-a-filtered-list-of-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `fnmatch` pattern [is not a regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/fnmatch.html). Things like `(?!...)` won't work.

Generally, exclusive patterns will not work well with `fnmatch`. You can to something like this

```
[!u][!a][!t]
```

to match any three letters that are not "uat"... but that would still mean you'd implicitly require at least 3 letters, and you could not control any further which ones.

Spare yourself the hassle, use `fnmatch` to get into the general ballpark, and then use a second step to exclude things you don't want.

```
files_dir = '/some/dir'
config_files = os.listdir(files_dir)

for file_name in config_files:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, toapex_pattern) and not "uat" in file_name:
        print(file_name)
```

Alternatively, use regex from the start.

```
import re

files_dir = '/some/dir'
config_files = os.listdir(files_dir)

# ...

toapex_pattern = re.escape(market) + '.*2apex.*' + re.escape(client) + '(?!uat).*\\.xml$':

for file_name in config_files:
    if re.match(toapex_pattern, file_name):
        print(file_name)
```

---

Just throwing it in, you could call the script as `python /test/scripts/regex.py nomura fiot b` and use `sys.argv[1]`, `sys.argv[2]` and `sys.argv[3]` directly, without having to split anything yourself first.