# Reading csv file with partially variable name

Tags: python, csv

I want to read a csv file into a data frame from a certain folder with pandas. This folder contains several csv files. They contain different information.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\User\Username\Desktop\Statistic\12345678_Reference.csv')
```

The first part in the filename (1 - 8 is variable). I want to read it in the file which ends with **'_Reference.csv'**, but I have no clue how to manage it. I googled, but could not find a solution if there are more than one csv file in the same folder.

Comment: See [Get a filtered list of files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225564/get-a-filtered-list-of-files-in-a-directory).

Comment: yes, using glob is the way to handle multiple files with similar names, maybe it will be worthwhile to use some regex too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `import os`, then you can use functions for for navigating the file system.

`os.listdir(path)` will return a list of all of the file names in a directory.

`[f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith("Reference.csv")]`

Will return a list of all files names ending with "Reference.csv". In your scenario, it sounds like there will be only one item in the list.

So, `[f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith("Reference.csv")][0]` would return the filename that you're looking for.

Then you can construct a path using the filename, and feed it to pd.read_csv().

Comment: Hi

Thanks so far, but it is not providing any results.
I define the path with:
`folder_path = 'C:\User\Username\Desktop\Statistic\''`

and then:

`[f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith("Reference.csv")][0]`

But the console is not providing any file name nor an error and the file is existing in that folder.

Comment: Based on your comment, you have the folder path, and you have the filename, but you don't have the file name assigned to a variable. 

folder_path = 'C:\User\Username\Desktop\Statistic\'
filename = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith("Reference.csv")][0]

file_path = folder_path + filename


Then feed the file path to the pandas function that you were using.