# Copy specific files from directory with just a small part from files given

Tags: python, file, copy, shutil

I want to copy all files from a directory to a new folder.
But there are multiple files in subfolders and i just want to copy all files with "NFL_V2" in it.

I am using python and tried this with os and shutil.

Dont know how to look for files with these letters and als if .find is the correct way-

Thanks!

---

UPDATE
I could solve this issue by using glob.glob()

Find the fixed code below!

```
source_dir = r"C:\folders\SHP_20211001"
dest_dir = r"C:\folders\DKM_NFL"

keyword = "NFL_V2"

for fname in glob.glob(source_dir+"/**", recursive=True):
    if keyword in fname:
        shutil.copy(fname, dest_dir)
        print("Copied " + fname + " to new folder")
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/how-to-use-glob-to-find-files-recursively

Comment: Since i cannot edit my post, here`s my updated code:

keyword = r"*\*NFL_V2*.*"

for fname in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if keyword in fname:
        shutil.copy(fname, dest_dir)
        print(fname)

Comment: yes, rather than `os.listdir()` try `pathlib.Path.rglob()`

Comment: i splitted my script in single parts. the copy function is working. So i think there is a problem with search function for the wanted files

Comment: can you update your code with your current attempt using `pathlib.Path.rglob()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a filtered list of files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225564/get-a-filtered-list-of-files-in-a-directory)