# randomly choose 100 documents under a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are about 2000 documents under the directory. I want to randomly select some documents and copy them to a new directory automatically.

[Some relevant information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701402/best-way-to-choose-a-random-file-from-a-directory) about generating one document name under a certain directory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
import shutil, random, os
dirpath = 'your/read/location'
destDirectory = 'your/destination'

filenames = random.sample(os.listdir(dirpath), 100)
for fname in filenames:
    srcpath = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(srcpath, destDirectory)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'shutil' is not defined? Do I need to import something?

Comment: Yup! Import `shutil` and `random`

Comment: If you are getting an "Errno 13: Permission Denied", try using shutil.copy() rather than shutil.copyfile().

Comment: shutil.copyfile(srcpath, destDirectory) was giving error, I used shutil.copy(srcpath, destDirectory), it woorked for me

Comment: filenames = random.sample(os.listdir(dirpath), 100). This line is giving me same file 5 times.

Comment: @JTN: please post an MCVE of the error and I'll take a look

Answer (score 4):

```
import shutil, random, os
dirpath = 'your/read/location'
destDirectory = 'your/destination'

filenames = random.sample(os.listdir(dirpath), 100)
for fname in filenames:
    srcpath = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
    destPath = os.path.join(destDirectory, fname)
    shutil.copyfile(srcpath, destPath)
```

Based off the answer by @inspectorG4dget (and edited by @olinox14), I found this minor adjustment worked best for my situation. I kept getting a 'IsDirectoryError' from shutil.copyfile() so I checked out the docs and realized the function copies to files (not directories). This adjustment preserves the filename in a new directory.