# MacOS 11: Randomly select several files from one location and copy to another location?

Tags: macos, finder

I need to select 135 random files from one location and copy it to another different location in MacOS.

Do you know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [randomly choose 100 documents under a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372054/randomly-choose-100-documents-under-a-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here by @tomc for 50 files

```
cp $(ls | sort -R | head -50) targetdir/
```

in my case would be:

```
cp $(ls | sort -R | head -135) targetdir/
```