# Python randomly playing VLC files in specific folder

Tags: python

I am trying to have it so that I can randomly play vlc files I have inside a specific folder, however I am getting the error.

```
>>> media.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'media' is not defined
```

I have navigated to the correct directory and the file is called media.py

My Code:

```
import os, random, subprocess
def rndmp(self):
   randomfile = random.choice(os.listdir("F:\\Work\\Python\\"))
   file = 'F:\\Work\\Python\\'+ randomfile
   subprocess.call(['F:\\Apps\\VLC\\vlc.exe', file])

rndmp()
```

Following this guide:
[Best way to choose a random file from a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701402/best-way-to-choose-a-random-file-from-a-directory)

And used another one which dealt with using subprocess to run vlc.exe

I am very new to python so I think I am missing something simple.

Comment: The error isn't here? Do you have a variable called media somewhere?

Comment: No the only media is the file name

Comment: Is this your full code?

Comment: Yes this is everything.

Comment: How do you run the script ? Can you print os.listdir(...) ? maybe you are trying to open a directory with vlc.

Comment: He typed `media.py` in the Python REPL. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @VincentSavard No Wonder D:, He didn't have the REPL shown when I asked a the questions.

Comment: I guess you are in windows? Open powershell, cd into the directory, and execute by doing ./media.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in how you are trying to run your file.

To run from Python (like you tried earlier):

```
>>> import media
>>> media.rndmp()
```

Or open command line (if you are in Windows) and type:

```
python media.py
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this is my first program I thought I was following my guide correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a .m3u file and play that via Python. Coincidentally I wrote a script just for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from threading import Timer

dir = "C:\Users\M4Shooter\Desktop\Music" # This is the directory where the audio files are, you can make it something like
                                         # C:\Users\M4Shooter\Desktop\Music\file.mp3 too, just to play a specific file

print "Playing ", dir
playlist = open('playlist.m3u', 'w')        # Create a temp playlist (if not present)
playlist.truncate()                         # Truncate / Erase the file data
playlist.write(dir + '\n')                  # Write's the directory path in 'dir' to the file
playlist.close()
os.system("playlist.m3u")                   # Opens the file with the default media player
remove = lambda : os.remove('playlist.m3u') # Function to remove the file
removeFile = Timer(20.0, remove)            # We need to wait for some seconds before removing the file,
removeFile.start()                          # To make sure that the media player loads the playlist
```

This code runs great on my system, you might want to add some conditional statements to check if the file exists before execution.

You can also replace 'dir' value with a path to an audio file. That way it will only add that specific file in the .m3u playlist.