# Unique Random File Selector Generator

Tags: python, random, generator, file-listing

I have a directory with a large number of files. I don't want to keep all the file names in memory, but I want to randomly get a subset of these files using a generator.

I can do this using information found in the post "[Best way to choose a random file from a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701402/best-way-to-choose-a-random-file-from-a-directory)", but I would like to make sure that my generator never returns the same file twice. So eventually after running the generator (which would return batches) I would have cycled through the entire list of files in the directory.

The methods I can think of still creates a file list to compare against (Create a list of already used file names and return if not in list) and would take longer to execute the more times the generator yielded results.

Is there a way, if I create an array of numbers equal to the number of files in the directory, that when I randomly pop a value from the array, I could get the file at that position? (I think this would take up significantly less memory than an array of strings)

From current comments I have the following code:

```
def GetRandomFileListGenerator(self, path):

    fileList = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
    random.shuffle(fileList)

    while(self.batchSize < len(fileList)):
        yield fileList[:self.batchSize]
        fileList = fileList[self.batchSize:]
```

Comment: _"I think this would take up significantly less memory than an array of strings"_. Well, define "significantly less". On my machine, an integer is 14 bytes, and a string is 25+len(the_string) bytes, so for strings with a dozen characters or so, using a list of integers only reduces your memory usage by a factor of three. Unless you're already straining against the limits of the system, anything less than an order of magnitude of savings doesn't seem all that worthwhile to me.

Comment: If you drop the integer array requirement, then selecting N unique elements from a collection is easy - just call [`random.sample(the_filenames, N)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

Comment: As for the "pick random index": Note that there is in general no guarantee that files in a directory are ordered!

Comment: Sorry I realized that I forgot to expand on something. As I run the generator over and over I eventually want to go through the entire list of files in the directory. Not just get a random unique sample once. But never repeat the same value in any future sampling, until the list of files has been exhausted.

Comment: No problem, just call `random.sample(the_filenames, len(the_filenames))`. Then it will iterate over every filename exactly once, and then become exhausted. Alternatively, call `random.shuffle` on the list once before iterating over it.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if files are added/deleted to the directory *while* the generator is yielding paths?

Comment: You can assume that the contents of the directory will be static. I can make sure that no new files are added until after the execution of this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned this approach in the comments, but I don't know if I explained it well, so I'll elaborate here.

You can use `random.sample` to get multiple values from a collection without duplicates.

```
import random

def iterate_over_files_randomly():
    the_filenames = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
    for filename in random.sample(the_filenames, len(the_filenames)):
        yield filename

for filename in iterate_over_files_randomly():
    print(filename)
```

You can also shuffle the list and iterate over that.

```
import random

def iterate_over_files_randomly():
    the_filenames = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
    random.shuffle(the_filenames)
    for filename in the_filenames:
        yield filename

for filename in iterate_over_files_randomly():
    print(filename)
```

In either case, the generator will go through the entire list of files in the directory, never repeating in any future sampling, until the list of files is exhausted. Sample output:

```
b
c
f
e
d
a
```

Both approaches have O(N) run-time. In other words, each additional value yielded takes the same amount of time as previous values yielded. This is due in part to the fact that the generator function does not slice or otherwise manipulate the list within its `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the solution from the question you mention by adding a `set` and check it's length. Here is an example:

```
import os
import random

random_filenames = set()
all_files = os.listdir("./")

while len(random_filenames) < 5:
    random_filenames.add(random.choice(all_files))
```

As for the memory consumption, you still need to load the whole list of the files unless you use some filename pattern to avoid listing and loop it with `itertools.cycle` and skip random number of files.

Comment: The while loop is a very inefficient way of doing ``set(random.sample(all_files, 5))``. Worst case, given a large/small ``all_files`` and large number, this never terminates.