# How would i choose a random image from a directory? Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

My program's goal is to take a random png image and places it against another random image. So far i have it so it gets the image, pastes it onto another, and saves it and would like to get it to be random.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter

France = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Epicd\Desktop\Fortnite\France.png")
FranceRGB = France.convert('RGB')
Crimson_Scout = Image.open(r"C:\Users\Epicd\Desktop\Fortnite\Crimson_Scout.png")

FranceRGB.paste(Crimson_Scout, box=(1,1), mask=Crimson_Scout)
FranceRGB.save(r"C:\Users\Epicd\Desktop\Fortnite\Pain1.png")
```

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: This might help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701402/best-way-to-choose-a-random-file-from-a-directory

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this would be to list the files in a directory, and choose randomly from the given paths. Something like this:

```py
import os
import random

random.choice(os.listdir("/path/to/dir"))
```

It would probably be smart to add in some logic to ensure you are filtering out directories, and only accepting files with specific extension (pbg, jpg, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) to get a list of the paths of all the items in a directory. Then use the [random class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) to select items from that list.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick 2 random `*.png` files from the working directory like this:

```
import glob
import random

all_pngs =  glob.glob("./*.png")
randPng1 = random.choice(all_pngs)
randPng2 = random.choice(all_pngs)
print randPng1
print randPng2
```

Then you can these two variables(`randPng1` and`randPng2`) instead of the hardcoded paths to your images.

If randomly picking the same png twice is not what you want, then you need to remove the `randPng1` element from the `all_pngs` array, before getting the second random element from the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.choice` and `os.walk` for that task.

The code for picking an image would something like this:

```py
import os
import random

path = "path/to/your/images.png"

images = []

# This will get each root, dir and file list in the path specified recursively (like the "find" command in linux, but separating files, from directories, from paths).
# root is the full path from your specified path to the the directory it is inspecting
# dirs is a list containing all the directories found in the current inspecting directory
# files is a list containing all the files found in the current inspecting directory
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    # This will filter all the .png files in case there is something else in the directory
    # If your directory only has images, you can do this:
    # images = files
    # instead of filtering the '.png' images with the for loop
    for f in files:
        if f[-4:] == '.png':
            images.append(f)

print(random.choice(images))
```