# discord py how to make bot send random image from folder

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am new to Python, I was looking for a code to send an image, but I found only a working code for sending one image -

```
await ctx.send('Working!', file=discord.File('image.png'))
```

I wanted to find the same one only for sending a random image from a folder.

Who knows how to do this?

I searched the forums for codes, but they do not work and I don’t know how to write it.

Comment: if you want random file then first get all filenames form folder - ie. `os.listdir()` - and later use some function from module `random` to select random name from list.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, so you have the code to send one image. Now splitting the tasks into two parts, all you need to do is get a random image from a folder! This can be done in a couple ways, but one is [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701402/best-way-to-choose-a-random-file-from-a-directory). That one only works if your folder only contains images, but even then, the point is that you can split a seemingly difficult task into smaller sub-tasks and get to your answer much more educationally and effectively.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can't find example for `discord` but you can find many examples how to get all files from folder (or get only images) and how to select random element from list.

And all this can be used to create expected result.

---

You can use `os.listdir()` to get all names in current folder

```
filenames = os.listdir()
```

And later you can use some of functions in module `random` to select random element from list

```
import random

selected_file = random.choice(filenames)
```

and later you can use it in discord

```
await ctx.send('Working!', file=discord.File(selected_file))
```

---

If you want to get from different folder then you may use it as argument in `listdir()`

```
filenames = os.listdir(some_folder)
```

but later you have to also add folder to selected name

```
path = os.path.join(some_folder, selected_file)

await ctx.send('Working!', file=discord.File(path))
```

---

If folder may have other files - not only images - then you may have to filter list and keep only filenames with some extensions

```
filenames = os.listdir(some_folder)

filenames = [ name for name in filenames 
               if name.lower().endswith( ('.jpg', '.png', '.gif') ) ]
```

---

**BTW:**

Python has also `os.walk()` to get names from folder and all subfolders, and `glob.glob()` which can use simple patterns with `*` and `?` like `"some_folder/*.jpg"` to get only `.jpg` in some folder.

Comment: Thanks dude for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here is an edited piece of code I use for my bot.

```
import random
import os

# directory that has the images
images = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "images")

def select_random_image_path():
    return os.path.join(images, random.choice(os.listdir(images)))

@bot.command()
async def send_image(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Working!', file=discord.File(select_random_image_path()))
```

Structure for the files would be like this:

```
|   main.py
+---images
|       73doCML.jpg
|       BcAyMo7.jpg
|       eRcYeHL.jpg
|       HSlG1Gl.jpg
|       IDgfXn6.jpg
|       ljFuj1z.jpg
|       MmBXwZN.jpg
|       N0udyAV.jpg
|       xenAlf8.png
|       yc1kX4A.jpg
|       ZJubdTU.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I thought I couldn't find the answer

Comment: finally my bot works and throws memes 

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the images as links you could do this.

```
Images = [“link for image”, “link for image”, “link for Image”]`
@client.command()
async def image(ctx)
     await ctx.send(random.choice(Images))
```

This will choose a random image link and send it. Discord automatically converts it to a image... You can get the link by sending it to someone or in a server and then right-click on the picture and then copy link.

Comment: No, I want to use not a link to an image, but an image from a folder (well, or from my PC). So that the bot throws the image itself from the folder on my PC, more precisely.